# JQuery-getting th value of selected td in same row & th vertically up from same selected td

Tags: jquery, html

So I am creating an open hours selector with hour long gaps to select. When a certain TD is selected a check mark appears on it. after selecting a few & pressing the button SET I want to be able to get the text of the TH of the selected TD that is in same row & obtain the text of the first row TH that is vertically above the selected TD. Below is a picture of how the table looks, & the HTML & JQuery code I have made.

```
   <table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>12AM</th>
    <th>1AM</th>
    <th>2AM</th>
    <th>3AM</th>
    <th>4AM</th>
    <th>5AM</th>
    <th>6AM</th>
    <th>7AM</th>
    <th>8AM</th>
    <th>9AM</th>
    <th>10AM</th>
    <th>11AM</th>
    <th>12PM</th>
    <th>1PM</th>
    <th>2PM</th>
    <th>3PM</th>
    <th>4PM</th>
    <th>5PM</th>
    <th>6PM</th>
    <th>7PM</th>
    <th>8PM</th>
    <th>9PM</th>
    <th>10PM</th>
    <th>11PM</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>MONDAY</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
   <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Saterday</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <script>

 $('td').on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('entypo-check');

  });

 $('#set').click(function() {
    if ($('td').hasClass("entypo-check")) {
        $('td.entypo-check').addClass('disabled');
        $('td.entypo-check').removeClass('entypo-check');
        $(this).text('EDIT');
        var value=$('td.entypo-check').closest('tr').children('th').text();
      console.log(value);
    } else {
        $('td').removeClass('disabled');
        $(this).text('SET');
    }
});
</script>
```

[Hour Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA0jP.png)

Comment: Since you are binding the hours statically, you can find the index of td which is selected and determine the hours based on its position. Let say if you have selected the 4th <td> element in Monday then it has to be considered as 4AM. This is crude way of doing.

Comment: @Baskar already posted that =)

Comment: can I know after click the #set button what is the output you expect to get?

Comment: @ErickFumes Does my answer help? I added a working example now too.

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef when you click set I want to be able to obtain both the vertical th & first th value in the row of all selected td's

Comment: @ErickFunes I think I got it .. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your point you need to use `.each()` to loop through `entypo-check`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('td').on('click', function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('entypo-check');
  }); 
  $('#set').click(function() {
    $('td.entypo-check').each(function(i){
        var getDay = $(this).closest('tr').find('th').text();
        var getIndex = $(this).index();
        var getTime = $('table  tr:first-child  th').eq(getIndex).text();
        alert('Day: '+getDay+ '    Time: '+ getTime);
    });
  });

});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/eb6nxdeL/)

Comment: Thank You! This did the job exactly!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the jQuery [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function of the element in one row (to get its index, or column number in your case), and then highlight the same index using the CSS selector `nth-of-type()`.

Here's a simple example to show you how:

```
// get selected member from first row (pseudo function)
var index = $("tr:nth-of-type(1)").getSelected().index();

// get the value of the second row element (same column)
var value = $("tr:nth-of-type(2) > th:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").text();
```

See [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/j3y5324n/) on JSFiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan this is definitely along the lines of what I was looking for but I want to put it in the button #set function. How can I get both the vertical th & first th value in the row of all selected td's after set has been pressed. For example the alert should spit monday 12am, monday 1am, tuseday 3pm.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `click` event handler of the `td`, you can find the value with the following statement:

```
$('th:nth-of-type(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').html();
```

Here, `this` refers to the `td` on which the user clicked.

The `index` method returns the index of the element inside its parent, which you can then apply to the `th`s. We add one to this index because the first column (index zero) contains the weekdays.

By adding the statement to the event handler, it will look like:

```
 $('td').on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('entypo-check');

  var value = $('th:nth-of-type(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').html();
  });
```